# How to get the difference of UTC time in Tcl?

Tags: tcl

I have 1043549199 as start time and 1043550749 as end time and I need know the elapsed time. I believe this numbers are formatted in UTC timestamp. How do I achieve this in Tcl

Comment: Just subtract the two numbers? Those are [unix times](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) and are in seconds. The difference will thus be in seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1043549199` is not a time so much as a numeric timestamp, which is a count of seconds from the start of the Unix epoch (beginning of January 1970, in UTC). Getting the difference is trivial as they are *just* numbers: subtract one from the other.

```
set t1 1043549199
set t2 1043550749
set diff [expr {$t2 - $t1}]
puts "The interval from '[clock format $t1]' to '[clock format $t2]' lasted $diff seconds"
```

```
The interval from 'Sun Jan 26 02:46:39 GMT 2003' to 'Sun Jan 26 03:12:29 GMT 2003' lasted 1550 seconds
```

Comment: When I formatted it with: clock format 1554 -format {%H hours %M minutes and %S seconds}, it gives me 01 Hours 25 Minutes 54 Seconds, but it is only 25 minutes and 54 seconds NOT 1 hour and..,